# Cannot read property 'navCtrl' of undefined

Tags: angular, cordova, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

For hours I've been searching for a solution to this problem in my project to no avail. I've read many of the other "Cannot read property ... of undefined" posts, but can't seem to find a solution for mine.

Below is the relevant code in my project.

This is an Ionic 2 / Apache Cordova project and the page below is the Sign In Page for the app.  It is not one of the core app components, it is simply a regular page.

For some reason, the NavController is not being recognized in the onSignIn() method, but I have no idea why.  I've injected NavController in the constructor, and it doesn't look like I am failing to follow any known procedure that I am aware of, but it's still failing every time.

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HomePage } from './../home/home';

var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();

@Component({
  selector: 'page-signin',
  templateUrl: 'signin.html',
})

export class SignInPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public params: NavParams) {}

  onSignIn() {
    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
      console.log(result.credential.accessToken);
      console.log(result.user.displayName);
      this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A better way to solve this issue would be by using [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function
>   expression and does not bind its own this, arguments, super, or
>   new.target.

So your issue would be solved by just changing the `onSignIn` method like this:

```
  onSignIn() {
    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then((result) => {
      console.log(result.credential.accessToken);
      console.log(result.user.displayName);
      this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    });
  }
```

Notice the `(result) => {...}` instead of the `function(result) {...}`

Comment: Yes,This is the best solution.Thanks for the info :)

Comment: Thanks! I haven't tried this yet, but this does seem better!

Comment: I finished implementing your solution, and I can confirm that it is working perfectly. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad to hear that :)

Comment: you saved my life :*

Answer (score 1):

try like the below code:

```
let _this;

@Component({
  selector: 'page-signin',
  templateUrl: 'signin.html',
})

export class SignInPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public params: NavParams) {
    _this = this; //Either here or in onSignIn whichever called first
  }

  onSignIn() {
    _this = this; //Either here or in constructor whichever called first
    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
      console.log(result.credential.accessToken);
      console.log(result.user.displayName);
      _this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    });
  }
}
```

I think you are facing the problem because of the scope of `this`. In your case scope of `this` belongs to the function which is passed inside `then`.