# getElementById works only the first time

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I'm using Ionic 2 and trying to use `getElementbyId` on

```
 <ion-content padding>    
   <ion-list id="list"></ion-list>    
 </ion-content>
```

so that i can add items the following way:

```
var listIon=document.getElementById("list");    
var li = document.createElement("ion-item");    
li.innerText=usern+": "+mensaje;    
var p = document.createElement("p");    
p.appendChild(li);    
listIon.appendChild(p);
```

It works perfectly fine the first time, but if I exit the page and reopen it I get an error  saying that

> cannot read property appendChild on null

. I have already read other questions where they say that the script is not at the bottom. By taking in count that in Ionic you don't put the script in the html at all I don't know what could be causing this.

**Edit**

I have uploaded the files [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0tF4r9gp4ljczM2b2xnT1c5ZW8)  main problem is in chat-details, chat-details is opened from chat.

Comment: probably this issue happens when variables are not initialized properly .

Comment: apendChild on null in which line? 
p.appendChild(li);   OR listIon.appendChild(p); ?

Comment: How do you reopen the page after you exit it? By pressing the Back button?

Comment: Please show more code. Need the full context (class/function) containing the call

Comment: @OussamaBenGhorbel on listIon

Comment: @MrLister no I click an arrow that takes me back to the previous page

Comment: @AluanHaddad I have uploaded my code now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What exactly are you trying to do? I think you're thinking in an *old Jquery way*, but Ionic works on top of Angular2, so things are done in a different way.

I assume you want to append a new item to a list, which can be done by using *ngFor and an array of data. Or if you want to show a message under certain conditions, you can accomplish that by using *ngIf. **You should try to avoid referencing the DOM directly, and update the component code instead to change the data shown in the view.**

I've created this [demo plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gl3Nan?p=preview) just to show you how to do these things in a *Angular2 way*. Please let me know what would be the expected result, so I can update the plunker accordingly.

**Component code:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'app/home.page.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  private count: number;
  public users: Array<string>;

  public showMessage: boolean;
  public message: string;

  constructor() {
    this.count = 1;
    this.users = [];

    this.showMessage = false;
    this.message = 'This is a secret message!';
  }

  public addUser(): void {
    this.users.push(`User ${this.count++}`);
  }

  public toggleMessage(): void {
    this.showMessage = !this.showMessage;
  }

}
```

**View code:**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>HomePage</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <h2>Users</h2>
  <p *ngIf="showMessage">{{ message }}</p>
  <ion-list *ngFor="let user of users">
    <ion-item>
      <p>{{ user }}</p>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
  <button ion-button (click)="addUser()">Add a user</button>
  <button ion-button (click)="toggleMessage()">Togle message</button>

</ion-content>
```

Comment: I have tried what you wrote, however now I am getting the error "Cannot read property 'users' of null". I think the problem must be that I am trying to this inside a database reference which is called when there is a child added. On line 53 you can see I added what you posted. I tried to do it also in a seperate function, it just said the function was null.

Comment: Ok, that's a different error, and it's related to Arrow functions. You can read [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43418146/cannot-read-property-navctrl-of-undefined/43424024#43424024) for more details. Instead of doing `databaseRef.on("child_added",function(snapshot){ ... })` use an arrow function to keep `this` as a reference to the component. It'd be like this `databaseRef.on("child_added", (snapshot) => { // here you can use the same code and will work! })`

Comment: @sebasferreras Great! that worked! Im going to look more into that solution so that I can better understand why it wasn't working. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hope you can accept the answer then no? @PabloGarcia

Comment: @Sampath sorry, I'm a bit new, forgot to do it, thanks for the reminder!