# this.navCtrl is undefined after ajax success call

Tags: ajax, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Hello I am struggling to redirect the landing page after successful login to ionic3 apps. It always shows error: ERROR TypeError: "this.navCtrl is undefined" 
`doLogin(){
$.ajax({
       type: 'get',
       url: 'http://my_server_ip_address/php/login.php?u='+this.UserInfoForm.username+'&p='+this.UserInfoForm.password,
       success: function (res) {
            window.localStorage['userInfo'] = JSON.stringify(res);
            this.navCtrl.setRoot('clientDashboard');
       },
       error:function(){
            this.navCtrl.setRoot('LoginPage');

       }
});`
}

my constructor:

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private menu: MenuController) {
    this.menu.enable(true); // Enable sidemenu
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot read property 'navCtrl' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43418146/cannot-read-property-navctrl-of-undefined)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: The problem is the way you're using the `this` inside a callback, your passing a callback with `function` decorator and you need an `arrow function`.

Comment: thanks bro.. the arrow function solved my problem